# Avoid default index but keep explicitly defined index in AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

I have some properties that are only referenced in queries that require composite indices. AppEngine writes all indexed properties to their own special indexes, which requires 2 extra write operations per property.

Is there any way to specify that a property NOT be indexed in its own index, but still be used for my composite index?

For example, my entity might be a Person with properties `name` and `group`.  The only query in my code is `select * from Person where group = <group> and name > <name>`, so the only index I really need is with group ascending and name ascending.  But right now AppEngine is also creating an index on `name` and an index on `group`, which triples the number of write operations required to write each entity!

I can see from the documentation how to prevent a property from being used for indexing at all, but I want to turn off indexing only for a few indexes (the default ones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand currently, you can either disable indexing on a property all together (which includes composite indexes) or you are stuck with having all indexes (automatic indexes + your composite indexs from index.yaml).

There was some discussion about this in the GAE google group and a feature request to do exactly what you are suggesting, but I wasn't able to find it. Will update the answer when I get home and search more.

Comment: Ah, I found at least one issue with relevant details: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4231

Comment: That's the one I was looking for! Completely agree that it's a pain. In one application I was working on, a single put() generated 32 writes, but I only used non-composite index for 1 query, everything else was composite.